# MySQL error 2003 (hy000) cannot connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061)

Tags: mysql

I opened MySQL earlier but didn't do anything with it and I left to do some other stuff. When I came back and tried to open MySQL from Python, it says there's no connection. I tried a command in the MySQL command line that I had opened, but it gives me `error 2003` for everything I try. I closed it and tried to reopen it. I put in the password but it displays `error 2003` and closes instantly.

I tried to start `MySQL80` from the Windows services (Windows 7 SP1) but it says access is denied.

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/fix-error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111/

Comment: Service state is not RUNNING? solve this problem. Services applet says 'access denied'? Search for the reason, check and fix account which the service is staring as, check permissions in the filesystem and registry. Look MySQL server logs for warnings/errors - it can help to determine the problem point. Try to remove and reinstall service, try to reconfigure server, as a last chance remove and reinstall MySQL server.